# Unable to call services on NodeJs server in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-modules

my application consists of frontend(angular js) and backend (nodejs). I have 10 ids in a list and I want to iterate those list for each iteration need to pass the id to the server (node js) and get the data back to frontend. I could see from the console logs angular code is making all the 10 calls but the node js server code is processing only the first request.  Is there any solution for this. I am a begginer to Node Js .

Frontend angular js code:

```
 var getRMPDetails = function()
{
   var inputJson;
   for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.rmps.list.length; i++) {
       inputJson = {"input":  {  "rmp-uuid" : $rootScope.rmps.list[i]['id']}};
       rmpInventoryService.getRMPDetails(inputJson, function(data){
       console.log(data);
   });
  }
}

above controller code calls below service method

ris.getRMPDetails= function(input, successCbk){
                var uri = CONST.API_BASE + '/rpdDetails';
                PromiseHelper.postData(uri, input).then(function(data) {
                    successCbk(data);
                });
            };
```

Node js server code:

```
Ctrl.prototype.getRMPDetails = function ($done, $input, rmpService, $logger) {

    var topology = {};
    var input = $input.body;
    console.log('method called');  =>> this is called only first RMP ID
    rmpService.getRmpDetailsFromController(input, function(data){
        $done({"rmps" : data});
    });    
};

rmpService.getRmpDetailsFromController  => it is a custom service in Nodejs server
```

Comment: step one: figure out if angular is actually sending out more than the first. If it isn't, then your server-side code is irrelevant and you need to look at your loop.

Comment: yes angular is calling the service 10 times.

Comment: I'm kinda confused. you have angular code, that's calling a `getRMPDetails` method, that apparently is a node method? that makes no sense. One runs on the server, the other runs on the client....

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution using node async module.

```
rs.prototype.getRpmDetailsFromController = function(input, successCbk){

    var rpmDetailsList = [];
    async.each(input, function(rmp, callback){

           var rmpList={};
            rmpList.rmp = rmp;
            var inputJson = {"input":  {  "rmp-uuid" : rmp['rmp-uuid'] } };

            var deployReq = helper.createRequest('POST', inputJson, $config.controllerHostURL, null, function(data){

                try {
                    topology = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(topology && topology['output']['status'] == 'success'){ 
                        rmpDetailsList.push(topology['output']);
                        callback();
                    }else{
                        $logger.warn('ERROR :: from controller');
                    }

                } catch(e) {
                    $logger.warn('ERROR :: ', e);
                }

            }, function(){
                //error callback
            });
            deployReq.send();
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                $logger.error('one of the api failed, the whole thing will fail now');
                } else {
                        successCbk(rpmDetailsList);
                    }
        });
};
```

https://github.com/yongzhihuang/PentaCode/blob/master/AsyncJs/asyncEach.js

more about async https://github.com/caolan/async